# problem with installing java in my ec2 instance

Tags: installation

[root@ip-172-31-36-152 ec2-user]# yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
Last metadata expiration check: 0:34:13 ago on Fri Jul 21 08:06:26 2023.
No match for argument: java-1.8.0-openjdk
Error: Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk

how to install java-1.8.0-openjdk   in my ec2 instance